# I'm having trouble horizontally centering my h1 with zurb flexbox

Tags: flexbox, zurb-foundation-6, flexboxgrid

I'm new to flexbox, and I've tried applying align-center to the row class but, the h1 will not center. Could someone give me a hand with this, and explain to me why the align center is not working? Here is a code pen [Codepen](https://codepen.io/mike316/pen/rwbVmP)

```
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Foundation for Sites</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/app.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='header-section'>    
      <div class='title-bar' data-responsive-toggle='menu' data-hide-for='medium'>
        <button class='menu-icon' type='button' data-toggle></button>
        <div class='title-bar-title'>Menu</div>
      </div>
      <div class='top-bar' id='menu'>
        <div class='top-bar-left'>
          <ul class='dropdown vertical medium-horizontal menu' data-dropdown-menu>
            <li class='menu-text'>The American Dream</li>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='main-content'>
      <div class='row'>
        <div class='small-12 column'>
          <h1>And...Then, ZANG!</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/what-input.js"></script>
    <script src="js/vendor/foundation.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't see `align-center` anywhere in your code, but a simple `text-align: center` on the `h1` parent does the trick.  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JJVYer?editors=1010

Comment: Thanks for the help.